# Schema to save key-value pairs in a property - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

So, I have the following schema in my Mongoose:

```
// MODEL
const PortletSchema = new Schema({
    slug: String,
    version: String,
    environment: String,
    scap: Number,
    country: {
        type: String,
        uppercase: true
    },
    _keys: [{ key: String, value: String }]
});
```

Inside the "_keys" array, I want to save a key value JSON like this:

```
// EXPECTED WAY TO STORE DATA INSIDE THE _keys PROPERTIES
{
    [
        {"key": "value"},
        {"anotherKey": "Another Value" }
    ]
}
```

So that way, I can have "dynamic keys" inside the _keys property instead of defining it like:

```
// HOW I STORE THEM TODAY
[{ key: String, value: String }]
```

Why I want this?: This will be read by a Java application, through a service, and it expects to map that array to get the keys like this: `${anotherKey}`.

At the moment, prior to send the info to the Java app, I made a library to change the keys to the first mentioned way. So the java app is receiving them like the second fragment of code.

I hope I can store a json file inside the _keys so I will send the info the way I need it.

Any help or advice is very welcome!

Comment: Your expected json schema for `_keys` is not a valid json!

Comment: thanks @KayvanMazaheri, actually I forgot to put the correct property as it's now, it's like this:

    _keys: [{ key: String, value: String }]

Thanks!

Comment: You actually cannot "type" like this because what you are telling the schema to do is in fact to actually **ensure** that all entries follow the { "key": "data", "value": "data" }` pattern. So this schema says it **must** have the keys `"key","value"` and no other names. If you want it to be "variable" then you use `_keys: [Mixed]` or even just `_keys: []`. You "could" add custom validation to ensure that this is always **two** keys only for each object. But the schema type itself cannot do that alone.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn, that's what I needed, and it's working great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @NeilLunn suggested, I used the `_keys` value like this:

`_keys: []`

This allowed me to insert any type of object inside.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Map

```
const schema: Schema = new Schema({
    _keys: {
        type: Map,
        of: Object,
    },
 });
```

Check this:
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#maps